# Is it possible to have multiple out bindings in an Azure function when using the pre-compiled C# with attributes?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to have multiple out bindings in an Azure function when using the precompiled C# function with attributes?

e.g. a function triggers on a HTTP request, and the function both responds with a HTTP response and to a table storage

*EDIT: wrong target, it's HTTP and a document to a Cosmos DB collection*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a function with two output bindings, implemented with the latest VS2017 Preview tooling:

```cs
[FunctionName("MultipleOutBindings")]
public static HttpResponseMessage MultipleOutBindings(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [Queue("out-queue")] out string queueItem)
{
    queueItem = "My new queue message";
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, very appropriate as I'm using the pre-compiled C# in the VS2017 preview. But my mistake, I'm trying to get a http response and writing a document to a Cosmos DB collection, rather than table. Any idea of the attribute for that, as I can't see anything in the https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs

Comment: @SteveC I'm not sure which attribute you are asking for? `DocumentDB` attribute is for Cosmos DB.

Comment: Ah ha ... ta. That's exactly what I was looking for, I was trying to set the attribute to do the equivalent of the checkbox for "create db and collection if not exists" ... which is in the DocumentDBAttribute.cs (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB/DocumentDBAttribute.cs) as CreateIfNotExists

Comment: So: your 1 **input** binding is HttpTrigger (marked as input because it's a "Trigger") and then your 2 **output** bindings are Queue and HttpResponseMessage, is that right? And the queue is specified in the parameters but the HttpResponseMessage is implicit in your return type?

Comment: @icanfathom Yes. You could add more output bindings if needed.

Comment: What about async functions? They can't use `out` params.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the following code snippet shows this example:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, CloudTable table, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

    // Set name to query string or body data
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    // insert to the table
    table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(new Request {PartitionKey=name, RowKey=Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data) }));

    return name == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
}

public class Request : TableEntity
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

and the bindings:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "table",
      "type": "table",
      "connection": "myStorage",
      "tableName": "myTable",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While it's totally possible to do this in a single function, you might also want to check out the [Durable Functions Fan-In/Out mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-concepts#fan-in-out).

You will end up with multiple, small, functions. Each doing their own thing.

Comment: the link is broken